# dockerfile copy instruction: what is "in" word for?

Tags: copy, dockerfile

In the image history of the  the hello-world Docker image, there is a line:

COPY file:7bf12aab75c3867a023fe3b8bd6d113d43a4fcc415f3cc27cbcf0fff37b65a02 **in** /

(you can also see this line on this page: https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/hello-world/remote/linux.md)

What is the "**in**" word for? I did not see "in" in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Answer (score 1):

The output of the `docker image history` doesn't use the same syntax as the Dockerfile used to create it.

To illustrate, I've created a statically-linked "Hello, world" program with Go, and a tiny Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM scratch
COPY hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

Let's build the Docker image.

```
$ docker build -t tmp_copy .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.15MB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 2/3 : COPY hello /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bfccb234abde
Step 3/3 : CMD ["/hello"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 96121e4a4504
Successfully built 96121e4a4504
Successfully tagged tmp_copy:latest
```

Now we can run it:

```
$ docker run tmp_copy
Hello, world.
```

Ok. Now let's look at the Docker image history output, without truncation:

```
$ docker image history --no-trunc tmp_copy         
IMAGE                                                                     CREATED             CREATED BY                                                                                           SIZE                COMMENT
sha256:96121e4a450418af93dbae993234a62868f0ce504e6884bcdfc6228dcaa3656d   15 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/hello"]                                                                    0B                  
sha256:bfccb234abdec088ccab38822c3e047c5f5e4e410f5db77db7f19a0d8f76c6df   15 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:ba2740c89a3e5e31ef2669cc67fccde9458c750e1f82bf1181dfe8f5ffdd827d in /    558kB
```

There's our curious `in /` in the `CREATED BY` column. We have two image layers here, both identified by their own hash. They both match the truncated hashes in the output of the `docker build` command above.

We can see that our instructions in the Dockerfile were parsed and rewritten in a slightly different form in the history output. The `file:<hash>` part appears to be added in the `copyInfoForFile` function of Docker's [copy module](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/0db8310ec1af8f278485224439853052d14c9861/builder/dockerfile/copy.go#L334).

If you copy that output into a Dockerfile and try to run it, you'll get something like this:

```
$ docker build -t tmp_copy2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.15MB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 2/3 : COPY file:ba2740c89a3e5e31ef2669cc67fccde9458c750e1f82bf1181dfe8f5ffdd827d in /
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder853347951/file:ba2740c89a3e5e31ef2669cc67fccde9458c750e1f82bf1181dfe8f5ffdd827d: no such file or directory
```

So where does it come from? We can see that the [format string](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/39e6def2194045cb206160b66bf309f486bd7e64/builder/dockerfile/internals.go#L168) for the copy command's "comment" field includes the mysterious `in`.
The [comment is then stored](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/39e6def2194045cb206160b66bf309f486bd7e64/builder/dockerfile/internals.go#L340) in that layer configuration's `Cmd` field along with the `#(nop)` we saw in the history output.

So it would seem that this output is for informational purposes only and not an exact record of the original Dockerfile commands.